# Is there a better way to stack 36 monthly snapshots of employee department assignments in SQL other than 36 blocks unioned together?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a table with monthly snapshots of all employees by department.  My source table is a list of transactions:

```
Employee A - Dept 1 - 1/1/2020
Employee A - Dept 2 - 7/1/2021
Employee B - Dept 1 - 10/1/2022
```

I've figured out how to do one snapshot, and using UNION ALL to stack them.  My next step is to copy paste my query 36 times and edit the month index by minus one so I have a running 36 months of snapshots.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to write the query to achieve the same end, since I know having the same block of code 36 times with only one element changing per instance is inefficient.

```
select associate_id, position_effective_date, home_department_code, 
most_recent_record, (last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
month(current_date())-1,1),month)) AS month

from(

select v_dept_history_adj.associate_id,             
v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code, 
v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date, max(position_effective_date) 
OVER(PARTITION BY v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
from src_table
where v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= 
last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
month(current_date())-1,1),month))

where position_effective_date = most_recent_record

union all

select associate_id, position_effective_date, home_department_code, 
most_recent_record, (last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
month(current_date())-2,1),month)) AS month

from(

select v_dept_history_adj.associate_id, 
v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code, 
v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date, max(position_effective_date) 
OVER(PARTITION BY v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
from src_table
where v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= 
last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
month(current_date())-2,1),month))

where position_effective_date = most_recent_record

order by month desc, position_effective_date desc
```

Comment: Instead of giving date ranges, can  you instead group by date_trunc(month, date) as part of your query?  I'm not following all of your logic for the snapshot, so thought this might quickly get you where you need to go.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this would give an idea on the approach

```
select associate_id, position_effective_date, home_department_code, 
most_recent_record, (last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
month(current_date())-Q_LEVEL,1),month)) AS month
from(
   WITH Q AS (SELECT LEVEL Q_LEVEL FROM DUAL A CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 36)
   select Q.Q_LEVEL Q_LEVEL, v_dept_history_adj.associate_id,             
   v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code, 
   v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date, max(position_effective_date) 
   OVER(PARTITION BY v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
   from src_table, Q
   where v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= 
   last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
   month(current_date())-Q.Q_LEVEL,1),month))
where position_effective_date = most_recent_record
order by month desc, position_effective_date desc
```

Comment: thanks!  i get Error: PRIOR keyword is missing in Connect By statement. (line 5) when i put this in

Comment: I run this in Oracle and it works fine. For which DB are you checking?

Comment: Sankar - snowflake.

Comment: You can implement a similar thing in that database.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to write that?