# Snowflake - invalid identifier 'LEVEL'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When running this query, I'm getting an error in Snowflake: invalid identifier 'LEVEL'

Also, I had some help putting parts of the query together, and I'm confused by origination of reference to 'Q'.  In the two 'from' clauses in the query, I don't understand where Q is pulling from - I don't have a table called 'Q' to pull from.

```
WITH Q AS (SELECT LEVEL Q_LEVEL FROM DUAL A CONNECT BY PRIOR LEVEL <= 36),
Q1 AS (
select 
    Q.Q_LEVEL Q_LEVEL
    , v_dept_history_adj.associate_id,             
    v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code, 
    v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date
    , max(position_effective_date) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
from datawarehouse.srctable, Q
where v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= 
last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
month(current_date())-Q.Q_LEVEL,1),month))
select 
    associate_id
    , position_effective_date
    , home_department_code, 
    most_recent_record
      , (last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date())
    ,month(current_date())-Q_LEVEL,1),month)) AS month
    FROM Q1
where position_effective_date = most_recent_record
order by month desc, position_effective_date desc
```

Comment: Q is being defined right there, on the first row. And what are you trying to do with DUAL? Can you simplify the problem, or tell us what result you are expecting to get?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa link below to the problem description.  In that post, I show the approach that works, but it is inefficient since it repeats the query once for each of 36 months I am trying to snapshot.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156119/is-there-a-better-way-to-stack-36-monthly-snapshots-of-employee-department-assig/74156483?noredirect=1#comment130935632_74156483.

Comment: I'm glad Simeon was able to resolve this with the given context!

Answer (score 0):

So in Oracle

```
SELECT LEVEL 
FROM DUAL A 
CONNECT BY PRIOR LEVEL <= 36
```

would give the rows 1 -> 36, in Snowflake need to use:

```
select row_number() over(order by null) as q_level
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>36));
```

```
last_day(date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 
month(current_date())-Q.Q_LEVEL,1),month)
```

is the same as:

```
last_day(dateadd(month, -q.q_level, CURRENT_DATE), month)
```

at which point that should be moved into the `Q` CTE for read ability:

```
WITH Q AS (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by null) as q_level,
        last_day(dateadd(month, -q_level, CURRENT_DATE), month) as last_day_month
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>36))
), Q1 AS (
    select 
        q.last_day_month
        ,v_dept_history_adj.associate_id             
        ,v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code
        ,v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date
        ,max(position_effective_date) OVER (PARTITION BY v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
    from datawarehouse.srctable
    join Q
        on v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= q.last_day_month
)
select 
    associate_id
    ,position_effective_date
    ,home_department_code
    ,most_recent_record
    ,last_day_month AS month
FROM Q1
where position_effective_date = most_recent_record
order by month desc, position_effective_date desc
```

So in the question, it was asked "where does Q come from" Q is the first of the CTE's or [Common Table Expression](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html), with the the two blocks of

```
WITH cte_name (
    <valid sql selection>
)
```

The above SQL from logical perspective could be as:

```
with cte_q as (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by null) as q_level,
        last_day(dateadd(month, -q_level, CURRENT_DATE), month) as last_day_month
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>36))
), cte_q1 as (
    select 
        q.last_day_month
        ,v_dept_history_adj.associate_id             
        ,v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code
        ,v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date
        ,max(position_effective_date) over(partition by v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
    from datawarehouse.srctable
    join cte_q
        on v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= q.last_day_month
)
select 
    associate_id
    ,position_effective_date
    ,home_department_code
    ,most_recent_record
    ,last_day_month AS month
from cte_q1
where position_effective_date = most_recent_record
order by month desc, position_effective_date desc
```

OR `cte_q` could be just a sub-query:

```
with cte_q1 as (
    select 
        q.last_day_month
        ,v_dept_history_adj.associate_id             
        ,v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code
        ,v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date
        ,max(position_effective_date) over(partition by v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
    from datawarehouse.srctable
    join (
        select 
            row_number() over(order by null) as q_level,
            last_day(dateadd(month, -q_level, CURRENT_DATE), month) as last_day_month
        from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>36))
    ) as q
        on v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= q.last_day_month
)
select 
    associate_id
    ,position_effective_date
    ,home_department_code
    ,most_recent_record
    ,last_day_month AS month
from cte_q1
where position_effective_date = most_recent_record
order by month desc, position_effective_date desc
```

and then the `cte_q1` can also be just a sub-query, but the "main" query is just filtering results, so that can be pushed into a QUALIFY clause:

```
select
    ,v_dept_history_adj.associate_id
    ,v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date
    ,v_dept_history_adj.home_department_code
    ,max(position_effective_date) over(partition by v_dept_history_adj.associate_id) AS most_recent_record 
    q.last_day_month as month
from datawarehouse.srctable
join (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by null) as q_level,
        last_day(dateadd(month, -q_level, CURRENT_DATE), month) as last_day_month
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>36))
) as q
    on v_dept_history_adj.position_effective_date <= q.last_day_month
qualify position_effective_date = most_recent_record
order by month desc, position_effective_date desc
```

The major problem I see is that `v_dept_history_adj` seems like a view name, but it does not appear in the original tables/cte list, so I am not sure what the real code is really doing.

Comment: Simeon - thanks!  Snowflake is throwing me this error on your proposed solution: Syntax error: unexpected ')'. (line 6)

Comment: Ah - I think I figured it out.  There was an extra ) in the with Q segment and a comma missing from the Q1 as select column list.  It seems to be working now!  Thanks so much!  Also, the query performance was solid - 1.5 seconds vs. 15 seconds when I manually replicated the non-recursive single month version of the query 36 times and unioned them together.

Comment: Simeon - there is some unexpected behavior happening with this solution.  For a user who changed home_department_code, the query result is showing only the months for their most recent departments, and drops their prior history.  For users who have not changed home_department_code, the full history is shown.

Comment: Hey @Gavin, given home_department_code is never used in the SQL it being changed is non impacting to this SQL.